# Как сверстать блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Есть такой блок [image: блок]

При клике на при тариф информация в табличке должна измениться на другую.
Как это оптимально заверстать? 
Пока только пришло в голову дать id-шники таблице и кнопке и подгружать через jquery.

Comment: кажется, здесь самые обычные табы.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Сделал

Answer (score 1):

Решение уже было в английской версии - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735512/replace-div-content-onclick

Рабочий пример кода - http://jsfiddle.net/ha6qp7w4/4/

JQuery:

```
$('#btnClick').on('click',function(){
    if($('#1').css('display')!='none'){
    $('#2').html('Here is my dynamic content').show().siblings('div').hide();
    }else if($('#2').css('display')!='none'){
        $('#1').show().siblings('div').hide();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="1">
    My Content 1
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none;">
    My Dynamic Content
</div>
<button id="btnClick">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/147253)

Comment: ОК, добавил код в ответ.

Comment: Отлично! Теперь всё хорошо. Спасибо за ваш ответ :)